# keep distance between navbrand and nav-items on small screens

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-5

I am trying to keep a distance between navbrand and nav-items on medium and small screens so i am giving the nav-item pading top its working fine but it leaves a massive space between the items also i have tried to use jquery by adding a padding buttom to the logo but its not working perfectly and the logo is getting smaller .

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
              <img class="logo" src="./images/logo.png" height="120" alt="Logo">
          </a> 
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarCollapse">
              <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
                  <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Bio</a>
                  <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Merch</a>
                  <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Releases</a>
                  <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Videos</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item{

margin-top: 50px;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using bootstrap spacing classes, for example

```
mb-1 mb-lg-0
```

to navbar brand